# Triggering registered events in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, events

I am building a web application where I need to compare 2 different maps of the same area, I need for the events on one map to automatically be triggered on the other map.
I have so far: map2.events.triggerEvent(evt.type,evt.px);

There is a map compare at http://tools.geofabrik.de/mc/?lon=29.53125&lat=22.26877&zoom=2 but I have no idea how they achieved this event handling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to synchronize only moving and zooming of map, one simple solution is: listen moveend event on map, and then zoom other map to extent of current map.

```
map1 = new OpenLayers.Map('map1');
map2 = new OpenLayers.Map('map2');

map1.events.on({
    moveend: function(evt) {
        map2.zoomToExtent(map1.getExtent());
        
    }       
});

map2.events.on({
    moveend: function(evt) {
        map1.zoomToExtent(map2.getExtent());
    }       
});
```

Here's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LwPEd/2/

I was afraid at first, that there will be an infinite loop when zoomToExtent triggers new event, but it works.

Answer (score 4):

It's also possible to make the feedback instant, at the cost of complicating the code a bit (and causing potential performance problems if there are other events attached to the maps):

I used @user1702401's answer and their Fiddle as a template.

```
var mapFollow = function(mapA, mapB) {
    var syncMapHandler = function() {
        var aCenter = mapA.getCenter();
        var bCenter = mapB.getCenter();

        var coordsChanged = ((aCenter.lat !== bCenter.lat) ||
            (aCenter.lon !== bCenter.lon));

        if (coordsChanged) {
            mapB.moveTo(mapA.getCenter(), mapA.getZoom(), {
                dragging: true
            });
        }
    };

    mapA.events.on({
        'move': syncMapHandler,
        'zoomend': syncMapHandler,
        scope: this
    });
};

map1 = new OpenLayers.Map('map1');
map2 = new OpenLayers.Map('map2');

mapFollow(map1, map2);
mapFollow(map2, map1);
```

Live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/4Wf7W/5/